# How to do typedef for shared_ptr of templated class?

Tags: c++

I want to do like this:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<MyClass> Ptr;
```

so I can use like this:

```
void do(MyClass<int>::Ptr ptr)
```

however I'm getting

```
error: ‘MyClass<T>::Ptr’ is not a type
     void do(MyClass<T>::Ptr ptr);
```

Comment: Are you actually doing `void do(MyClass<int>::Ptr ptr)`, or do you have `template <typename T> void do(MyClass<T>::Ptr ptr)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica `do` is a member function of a templated class. Sory for not including it.

Comment: No worries.  When you want to do `void do(MyClass<T>::Ptr ptr)` you need `void do(typename MyClass<T>::Ptr ptr)` to tell the compiler that `ptr` is a type since it is a dependent name.